# creating a generalized rounding function in C

Tags: c, rounding

*Most the rounding questions on Stack Overflow are about specific cases and, as I just made a generic rounding function, I thought I would share it.*

---

I have a number *f*, a starting value *a*, and an increment *b*, and I want to “round” *f* to the nearest element of the set {*a* + *b*•*i* | *i* is an integer}. For example:

- `a` = `0.0`, `b` = `0.5`: round to one of the values `0.0`, `0.5`, `1.0`, `1.5`, etc.
- `a` = `0.25`, `b` = `0.5`: round to one of the values `0.25`, `0.75`, `1.25`, `1.75`, etc.
- `a` = `0.21`, `b` = `0.23`: round to one of the values `0.21`, `0.44`, `0.67`, `0.80`, etc.

The standard C library has [`roundf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/roundf.html) but it only rounds to the nearest integer.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Why are you asking a question then immediately answering it?

Comment: @EdHeal - Probably an attempt to give something to the community. The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) encourages it after all.

Comment: 0.23 cannot be represented as a float.

Comment: Shouldn't the 0.5 at the beginning of the 2nd bullet be 0.25?

Comment: @alk no since I still want the numbers to increment by 0.5.

Comment: Asking a *useful* question and posting the answer is just fine, @EdHeal.  Asking a question that has *no general value to the community* and posting the answer isn't that cool, however.  I can't imagine any case where this would be a useful function generally.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: I've worked with multiple scientific and graphical applications where a "snap value to nearest grid-point" operation (which is effectively what the OP is asking for, in 1d) is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float   round_float(float x, float inc, float start_val)
{
    return ( roundf( (x - start_val) / inc ) * inc + start_val );
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%f\n", round_float(12.522, 0.5, 0));
    printf("%f\n", round_float(12.522, -0.5, -0.1));
    printf("%f\n", round_float(5.318, 0.23, 125));
    printf("%f\n", round_float(-12.522, 12, 5));
    printf("%f\n", round_float(-12.522, 3.6, -2));

}
```

output:

```
12.500000
12.400000
5.400002
-7.000000
-12.799999
```

---

first example: `round_float(10.1521, 0.5, 0)`

second example: `round_float(10.1521, 0.5, 0.25)`

final example: `round_float(10.1521, 0.23, 0.21)`

---

#### Extended example

This code shows how random sample values are rounded to the nearest entry in each of three sequences specified by the starting value and the increment — using the values outlined in the question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

static inline float round_float(float x, float inc, float start_val)
{
    return roundf((x - start_val) / inc) * inc + start_val;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%f\n", round_float(12.522, 0.5, 0));
    printf("%f\n", round_float(12.522, -0.5, -0.1));
    printf("%f\n", round_float(5.318, 0.23, 125));
    printf("%f\n", round_float(-12.522, 12, 5));
    printf("%f\n", round_float(-12.522, 3.6, -2));

    static const float samples[] =
    {
        -14.2751, -12.3080, -10.5320,  -6.4804,  -1.0859,
          0.1999,   0.2099,   5.2980,   5.7819,  11.7052,
    };
    enum { NUM_SAMPLES = sizeof(samples) / sizeof(samples[0]) };

    static const float control[][2] =
    {
        { 0.00, 0.50 },
        { 0.25, 0.50 },
        { 0.21, 0.23 },
    };
    enum { NUM_CONTROL = sizeof(control) / sizeof(control[0]) };

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CONTROL; i++)
    {
        float a = control[i][0];
        float b = control[i][1];
        printf("Start: %8.4f; increment %8.4f\n", a, b);
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_SAMPLES; j++)
        {
            printf("  Sample: %8.4f rounds to %8.4f\n",
                   samples[j], round_float(samples[j], b, a));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
    12.500000
    12.400000
    5.400002
    -7.000000
    -12.799999
    Start:   0.0000; increment   0.5000
      Sample: -14.2751 rounds to -14.5000
      Sample: -12.3080 rounds to -12.5000
      Sample: -10.5320 rounds to -10.5000
      Sample:  -6.4804 rounds to  -6.5000
      Sample:  -1.0859 rounds to  -1.0000
      Sample:   0.1999 rounds to   0.0000
      Sample:   0.2099 rounds to   0.0000
      Sample:   5.2980 rounds to   5.5000
      Sample:   5.7819 rounds to   6.0000
      Sample:  11.7052 rounds to  11.5000
    Start:   0.2500; increment   0.5000
      Sample: -14.2751 rounds to -14.2500
      Sample: -12.3080 rounds to -12.2500
      Sample: -10.5320 rounds to -10.7500
      Sample:  -6.4804 rounds to  -6.2500
      Sample:  -1.0859 rounds to  -1.2500
      Sample:   0.1999 rounds to   0.2500
      Sample:   0.2099 rounds to   0.2500
      Sample:   5.2980 rounds to   5.2500
      Sample:   5.7819 rounds to   5.7500
      Sample:  11.7052 rounds to  11.7500
    Start:   0.2100; increment   0.2300
      Sample: -14.2751 rounds to -14.2800
      Sample: -12.3080 rounds to -12.2100
      Sample: -10.5320 rounds to -10.6000
      Sample:  -6.4804 rounds to  -6.4600
      Sample:  -1.0859 rounds to  -1.1700
      Sample:   0.1999 rounds to   0.2100
      Sample:   0.2099 rounds to   0.2100
      Sample:   5.2980 rounds to   5.2700
      Sample:   5.7819 rounds to   5.7300
      Sample:  11.7052 rounds to  11.7100
```

I'm sure a more judicious choice of sample values would make the point even clearer; those are just a collection of random numbers in the range -20 .. +20 in sorted order.

<sup>*Apologies for the extra level of indent in the last example.
The preview was not showing 'code' when it was not indented two levels, and I've no idea why. (Configuration: Firefox Quantum 57.0.1 (restart pending) on macOS High Sierra 10.13.2 and SO 2017.12.22.28257)*</sup>

Comment: Why is not enough just to use `round_float(my_float, precision)`? Why we need some `start_val` parameter? `round_float(12.61f, 0.1f) = 12.6f` and `round_float(12.66f, 0.1f) = 12.7f;` No need for any third parameter.

Comment: for example if I want to round a value to the nearest 0.5, but I wan't the number to end with 0.75 or 0.25, I would need a start value of 0.25

Comment: Doesn't make any sense. This is not the purpose of this function. Just round value to the nearest precision and that's it.

Comment: @tilz0R the function needed a start value for what I was doing. If you don't need a start value you can set it to 0, but since there are times it can be useful, in addition to the functions goal to be as generic as possible, I included it.

Comment: Sorry, but this is what makes function non-generic.

Comment: omitting a function parameter makes a function less generic. Perhaps you mean more confusing? But I thought I explained the use of the `start_val` well

Comment: Everything you need is input and precision. That's all, without any start value. Imagine `roundf` core function as having precision set to `1`. Your function just needs to implement precision parameter. Period. End of story.

Comment: Another problem is that this function is not correctly rounded.The functions result will, in the general case, be off by a few ULPs. Not to mention overflow and underflow, which will prevent the function giving the correct answer in cases where a correct answer (within the float type range) could be given.

Comment: @tilz0R so explain how your function rounds a number to to the nearest 0.5, 1.5, 2.5 ect...? A precision of 0.5 would not suffice since the value 2.2 would be incorrectly rounded to 2

Comment: @tilz0R: You have not presented any basis for the claim “This is not the purpose of this function.” It is absurd to claim the author’s purpose for a function is not the purpose for the function. If somebody wants to compute the element of {*a* + *b* • *i* | *i* is an integer} that is nearest to *x*, then it is perfectly fine to write a function to do that (or, in this case, to approximate it subject to floating-point rounding issues).